# what is wrong here in this python code?

Tags: python

What is wrong here in this code: I am just passing an existing file and then removing it using `os.remove()` and then writing it with another content. But the file shows the previous content not updated one. Snippet  here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os

arg1=sys.argv[1]
_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
os.remove(arg1)
hd = open(arg1, 'w')
for line in _list:
    hd.write(line)
hd.close()
```

Let's say my file contains the following content: **output1**:

```
p
q
r
s
```

After removing the file(`os.remove()`), re-creating the same file and over-writing it's content from the list. The expected output:

```
a
b
c
```

But I am getting `output1` instead of expected output.

Comment: What outcome are you after here?

Comment: the same as file contains before deleting ..

Comment: its seem fine, if file is created before executing program

Comment: @Totem, what i think , he just passing a existing file and then removing using `os.remove` then writing it with another content

Comment: run the code without the part after the remove. see if it is deleting the file(os.remove might be failing and swallowing the error). It may be possible that it is not. why not use w+ instead?

Comment: @thekindlyone I have checked it, file is recreated.

Comment: Am I missing something? isn't `os.remove` totally superfluous if the file is being opened in `'w'` mode?

Comment: take a look at this maybe? http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/658255-can-os-remove-followed-os-path-isfile-disagree

Comment: @thekindlyone even is os.remove() is failing,the new contents should be there.

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into a python file and ran it. I got your expected output (a,b,c) in the filename that I passed in. Not sure why it's giving you issues. What version of python are you using?

Comment: are you sure you are typing the argument correctly while running it?

Comment: @thekindlyone Yes.!! you can also check at your end if you want.

Comment: this is a weird thing. Not easily replicable. It will certainly work for me. What OS is this? Try doing an os.path.isfile(fname) right after the remove and see what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

You may simply want to open the file and write the current content without removing the file first:

```
with open(arg1, "w") as f:
    for line in _list:
        f.write(line)
```

This is how [open()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) works.

> The first argument is a string containing the filename. The second argument is another string containing a few characters describing the way in which the file will be used. mode can be 'r' when the file will only be read, 'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be erased), and 'a' opens the file for appending; any data written to the file is automatically added to the end. 'r+' opens the file for both reading and writing. The mode argument is optional; 'r' will be assumed if it’s omitted.

Comment: Yes, this will work. But why we are not getting expected output in my case ??

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe this has something to do with this from the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove): on Unix, the directory entry is removed but the storage allocated to the file is not made available until the original file is no longer in use.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 12.04